# Hide "Load More: button in a lazy load

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I would like to hide the "Load more" button if there are no more items with the **"display: none"** assigned to them. I have a filter that loads the HTML list based on a tour criteria – so the list is never the same.

E.g. If I only have one item or I only have 4 items and nothing to load, the load more button should be disabled or not visible.

I have the following HTML script:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

    var tour_block = $(".tour");

    // count elements and find how many have display none
    /*
     var size_li = tour_block.size();
     alert( size_li );
     */


    tour_block.slice(0, 6).show();

    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) { alert("dd");
        e.preventDefault();

        var hidden_tour = $(".tour:hidden");

        hidden_tour.slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if (hidden_tour.length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });

});
```

```css
.tour {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
  <div class="tour">some tour content</div>
</div>

<a id="loadMore" href="#">Load More Tours</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button for testing:

```
<button id="test-button">Test Button</button>
```

Use this script:

```
$('#test-button').on('click', function () {

    // Check if there are no hidden values (note ! prefix)
    // Select all with class 'tour' and filter for hidden items
    if (!$('.tour:hidden').length) {
        // Hide button
        $('#loadMore').hide();
    }

});
```

Hope it helps.